# Internal Server Error when accessing Eucalyptus console

Tags: vmware-workstation, eucalyptus

For test purpose, I installed Eucalyptus faststart on a VMWare Workstation virtual machine (CentOS 64 bits-6.6 Minimal).

Eucalyptus installs fine, but when trying to access to the console (port 8888), I got "Internal Server Error".

I checked the log files, but I could not find any clear message about the error.

VM network is configured with NAT (I suspect that the problem is around that).

I disabled iptables, and the antivirus, without success.

Anyone could successfully test Eucalyptus on a VM?

Thank you in advance,

Best regards,

Comment: I could access to the console, but, from the VM itself (Not from the host machine, where I got the error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did my tests in the VM, and Eucalyptus does not match my requierments.
Thanks!